# python paho client MQTT subscriber not getting

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using python Paho client.

I am using this in to my function.

my code is showing

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time, logging


broker = "127.0.0.1"

port = 1883
QOS = 0

CLEAN_SESSION = True
# error logging


# use DEBUG,INFO,WARNING
def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):  # create function for callback
    # print("subscribed with qos",granted_qos, "\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("sub acknowledge message id=" + str(mid))
    pass


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc=0):
    print("DisConnected result code " + str(rc))


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected flags" + str(flags) + "result code " + str(rc))


def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message received in mqtt_subscriber  " + msg)


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("message published " + str(mid))


topic1 = "test"
client = mqtt.Client("RDAresp", False)  # create client object

client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe  # assign function to callback
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect  # assign function to callback
client.on_connect = on_connect  # assign function to callback
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(broker, port)  # establish connection
time.sleep(1)
client.loop_start()
client.subscribe("RemoteDoorAccess")
count = 1
while True:  # runs forever break with CTRL+C
    print("publishing on topic ", topic1)
    msg = "message : RemoteDoorAccess_resp is published "
    client.publish(topic1, msg)
    count += 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

and in views.py

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):
    msg = str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("message  authority resp module  " + msg)


def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):  # create function for callback
    print("subscribed with qos", granted_qos, "\n")
    time.sleep(1)

    pass


def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc=0):
    print("DisConnected result code " + str(rc))


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected flags" + str(flags) + "result code " + str(rc))


def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("message published " + str(mid))


def mqttConnection():
    topic = "RemoteDoorAccess"
    client = mqtt.Client("RDA", False)  # create client object

    client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe  # assign function to callback
    client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect  # assign function to callback
    client.on_connect = on_connect  # assign function to callback
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect(broker, port)  # establish connection
    time.sleep(1)
    client.subscribe("test")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("publishing on topic ", topic)
    msg = "RemoteDoor Access published"
    client.publish(topic, msg)
    time.sleep(10)

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([])
def remotedooraccess_mobile(request):
        mqttConnection()
        return Response({msg: validation["FDP34"]}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Here the topic 'test' is published but not subscribing.

[image: subscriber]

please check views output

[image: view]

in my views.py on_message function is not called by the topic test.
how can I solve this.
I am totally stuck here.. in view.py subscribe function is not calling.

I am very new to mqtt.
please help

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post the actual text then use the tools to format it. Images can be hard to read, and are impossible for people who use screen readers.

Comment: @hardillb ok. I will do my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the client loop in your `views.py` code otherwise there is nothing to actually run your `on_message()` callback.

You should also move all your calls to `client.subscribe()` to into the `on_connect` callback and remove most of the calls to `time.sleep()`

Comment: thank you for your replay.. its working fine. thank you thank you :)